# Função update para atualizar data e hora?

Tags: c#

Tenho um **Windows Form**, na barra de controle (onde tem o Título, fechar e minimizar) tenho também a data e hora:

```
        this.hora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        this.data.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Mas não está atualizando sozinho, tentei fazer pegando o movimento do mouse e tecla pressionada, mas não da pra chamar as funções que executam isso toda hora..
Não sei, não tenho nem ideia de como se faz isso, só tinha visto C# no Unity e lá tinha a função pronta `Update` que fazia esse papel (ficava se atualizando e executando os comandos dentro dela), mas como faço isso no Visual?

Estou chamando assim:

```
 public Interface()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyPress += _keyPress;
        MouseMove += _mouseMove;

    }
    public void _mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.mouseLocation = e.Location;
        this.hora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        this.data.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    }
    public void _keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        this.hora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        this.data.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

Comment: Esse Form é o que? WPF, XAML?

Comment: Windows Form, .cs mesmo

Comment: Quando você chama as duas linhas? Em qual evento do Form?

Comment: coloquei aí no post.. essas funções são para captar tecla apertada ou mouse movimentado

Comment: São chamadas lá no inicio quando coloco elas na operação

Comment: Você precisa inserir um **Timer** no formulário, e no evento **tick** do timer colocar o seu código. Coloque a propriedade interval do timer em 1000 (milisegundos). Acho que o evento chama **tick**, mas se clicar duas vezes no timer é o evento que o visual studio cria automaticamente.

Comment: O timer serve exatamente para isso, ele chama o evento a cada N milisegundos.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, eu não sabia o que o Timer fazia direitinho, obrigado pela explicação, me ajudou até em outro treco que eu estava tentando fazer! Vlw

Comment: o evento é nomeDoTimer_Tick mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, declare esse timer:

```
 public Timer WithEventsnowUpdater = new Timer();
```

Agora coloque esse método:

```
 public override void OnLoad() {
      nowUpdater.Enabled = true;
      nowUpdater.Interval = 1000; /*1 segundo = 1.000*/
      nowUpdater.Tick += onLoad();
 } //ou coloque essas duas linhas no método Form1_Load()

 public void nowTick() {
      this.hora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
      this.data.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa Usar um Timer, para poder atualizar a data e/ou hora em um determinado intervalo de tempo a seu critério.
Veja [Aqui Maneiras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535722/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-timer)!)